# Fill a cell with text & find match of a reference cell from previous entries, then automatically fill the respective "semi-adjacent" cells with a word

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, tasks, list, if

I am doing a daily task list excel sheet containing columns titled Month, Day, Task, Status, and Update. Cells under Status have a dropdown list choice of either "done" or "missed", depending on if I completed the Task of that Day.

Supposed the task list sheet contains 4 days already, on Day 1 and Day 3 I have "missed" "brush teeth" task but I completed the same task on Day 4, what I need is when I click "done" on Day 4's Status cell, the Update cells of Day 1 and Day 3 will automatically be filled up with "completed". That means that when I clicked "done" on Day 4's Status, Excel will find a match of "brush teeth" from the previous Day's Task and automatically fill their respective Update cells with "completed"

[image: Visual explanation]

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(D2<>"done",COUNTIFS(C$2:C$5,C2,D$2:D$5,"done")>0),"completed","") by minyeh of reddit

Paste on E2 then drag downwards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).